# What is a good practice to avoid duplicated functions in React.js with 'this.setState' format?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
  @autobind
  setName(name){
    this.setState({name: name});
  }

  @autobind
  setLocation(location){
    this.setState({location: location});
  }

  @autobind
  setReference(reference){
    this.setState({reference: reference});
  }
```

All the functions placed above have a similar structure, and I would like to know if there is a good practice in React.js to avoid having to repeat myself to set different states.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a function that takes the object as a value, rather than the key value and pass it to `setState`

```
setValue(object) {
  this.setState(object)
}
```

and use it like:

```
<div onClick={() => this.setValue({ reference })} />
```

but then you may as well just call `setState` directly.

```
<div onClick={() => this.setState({ reference })} />
```

So really you don't need any of those functions because `setState` **is** that function.

However, this generalized `setValue` function could be useful when passing to children.

```
<Child setParentState={this.setValue} />
```

and use it

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.setParentState({ reference })} />
```

Though I admit I've never done anything like that. Seems to give too much control to child elements, but used sparingly should be fine.